# How to reset vim and neovim when sourcing wrong file .zshrc instead of init.vim

Tags: macos, vim, macos-catalina, neovim, zshrc

I'm using macOS Catalina which has built in Vim 8.1. I'm also using iTerm with zsh and oh-my-zsh. I installed neovim for my personal use and when I setting it up, I accidentally enter `source .zshrc` in Command mode instead of `source init.vim`. From then, when I open neovim or built in vim, it does not source `init.vim` anymore and shows error message like below:

```sh
Error detected while processing VIMINIT:
E33: No previous substitute regular expression
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There is a line in my .zshrc that exports VIMINIT variable

```sh
export VIMINIT="~/.config/nvim/init.vim"
```

How can I undo this or is there any other way to reset vim to original setting? Thank you so much

Comment: `$ unset VIMINIT` ?

Comment: Thanks @Niloct, I tried your solution and my vim and neovim is backed to normal

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Niloct solution, `unset VIMINIT` and vim/neovim is backed to normal. After that, I reopen the iTerm and it showed error message again. Therefore I removed the export line from `.zshrc` and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

To load a clean neovim:

```
nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
```

Actually I have an alias for that

```
alias vinone='nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE'
```

This way you can type `vinone` and use your default neovim